# Building classes based on user input

Tags: c#, winforms

I am creating a way to build automation which will allow users to enter commands via free-form textboxes with auto-complete, sort-of a pseudo-IDE functionality similar to intellisense.  To start, I am defining what amounts to a list of string which act as definition templates that will be used to collect parameters from the users of my application. For example, the sample template looks like:

```
var scriptTemplate = "show message '{v_Message}' and close after {v_AutoClose} seconds"
```

So above is the defined pattern that my application is expecting to find.  I anticipate looping over textbox data (happy path) that looks like:

```
"show message 'hello world!' //textbox1.Text
```

or

```
"show message 'hello world' and close after 4 seconds" //textbox1.Text
```

So, now I am building a method to take the user's input, compare it against the known templates, select a template and then extract the parameters (in this case `v_Message` and *potentially* `v_AutoClose`) and instantiate a class which will contain some logic to execute the command:

```
var newClassInstance = new CustomMessage();
newClassInstance.v_Message = "hello world";
//newClass.v_AutoClose = 4;
newClassInstance.Execute();
```

I am stuck on the part where I need to pull out the known parameters and apply them to the class as I am not sure the best way to go about this.  I was able to make the first 2 words 'reserved' keywords to select the correct template, but what is the best way to extract the parameters and apply them back to the class?  I am trying to do this generically for 100 different potential templates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have come across the similar type of requirement, where I have two tables with a column describing "TitleOfCampus", One of the tables is master and second one fresh data **(your form data)**. 
All I need to do is, map-it the fresh data to the matching data in master table **(Your template table)**.

I took each entry from fresh data(TitleOfCampus), filtered the master table by breaking the string value in TitleOfCampus as follows,

1. Actual full string based filter,
2. String.Split(" ") array keywords based filter

From the obtained results, then finally sort the matching master table info based on first letter of filter value TitleOfCampus, so the topmost data is the most matching info ready for mapping. Sample Code as follows

```
List<MyTemplate> templateDetails = new List<MyTemplate>
   //Your filter code
templateDetails.AddRange(actualFullStringMatchResults);
foreach(var item in searchKeyword.ToString().Split(" "))
 {
   //Your filter code
   templateDetails.AddRange(eachKeyWordMatchResults);
 }
 //Remove duplicate 
 templateDetails= templateDetails.DistinctBy(x => x.TempalteID).ToList();
 //Set topmost value as most releavant one
 templateDetails.OrderByDescending(i => i.TitleOfCampus[0] == fullStringFilter[0]).ToList();
```

I hope this concept will sort out your requirement. auto close template in stipulated time is not an important point here but showing the right template is important.

Comment: Splitting by string is not ideal because the parameters can contain strings which will make it not 1:1. For example `show message 'hello world'` would not translate well to `show message '{v_message}'`

Comment: @JasonBayldon, Am I clear with your problem, "User types some words, you need to use those words as a parameter to search and fetch from the 100 potential templates with most relevant one as suggestion added with auto close template suggested in few seconds. "

Comment: @JasonBayldon why do you want to translate back to `show message '{v_message}'`. It is not necessary bcoz it is actually showing the matching template not the keywords typed by the user.

Comment: The problem is I am trying to extract parameters from the text that the user supplied and instantiate a class.  Splitting by space would work but only if I can escape single quotes from being split as well as I cant guarantee that the user is not going to input spaces.  I need to pull out the parameters from a string based on the source pattern.

Comment: @JasonBayldon Keyword with or without `(space, " ' ")` is not a big deal. where does this single quote comes from? Can u give me a clear example with sample inputs by editing your question. These inputs shall be what you think as difficult to solve. I could sort your problem easily.